# What Privileges does vfork() child possess ?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, operating-system, kernel, aix

Does the process created with vfork() has same the same level of privileges that of a creator process i.e parent process ?

example : If I run a process as root does vfork() child possess the same execution privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Open Group (POSIX) specification of [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) says:

> The `fork()` function shall create a new process. The new process (child
>   process) shall be an exact copy of the calling process (parent
>   process) except as detailed below:

As there is no mention of UIDs/GIDs below that text, you can deduce that these properties are inherited.

These properties are eventually changed by calls to appropriate property changing functions (`setuid`, etc)  or `exec`.

The old (POSIX 2004 or earlier) specification of [`vfork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html) is similar:

> The `vfork()` function shall be equivalent to `fork()`, except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec` family of functions.

The specification of `vfork()` was removed from POSIX 2008 (aka POSIX 2016).

Comment: Does this apply to vfork() as well ? I am facing ( file access related) issues inside a vfork() call. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135880/webmethods-integration-servers-hang-in-hp-when-it-uses-a-third-party-java-api

Comment: Aravind share some of the code. If the process created via vfork modifies anything it will cause undefined bahvior which might be your problem.

Comment: @Aravind OpenGroup *The vfork() function shall be equivalent to fork(), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit() or one of the exec family of functions.*

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, does vfork() use the same file descriptors as that of parent? will closing the file descriptor in child process result in closing the same file descriptor in parent process too ?

Comment: As stated, don't do anything else than calling exit or exec... vfork() was designed to (possibly) optimize the pattern fork/exec but usage is restricted to nothing else than fork/exec because vfork is virtual-fork not a "real" fork.