# vfork() usage with pipe()

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

What I understood from man page is that **vfork()** child process uses the same resources that of parent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
        int     fd[2], nbytes;
        pid_t   childpid;
        char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
        char    readbuffer[80];

        pipe(fd);

        if((childpid = vfork()) == -1)
        {
                perror("fork");
                exit(1);
        }

        if(childpid == 0)
        {
                /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
                close(fd[0]);

                /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
                write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
                exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
                /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
                close(fd[1]);

                /* Read in a string from the pipe */
                nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
                printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
        }

        return(0);
}
```

As per my understanding

```
close(fd[0]); // In child
write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
```

The above code lines together in child process should result in **error no 13** **SIGPIPE** as we are closing the pipe read end fd[0]. But this is not happening 
insted the output is 
**`Received string: Hello, world!`**
Can anyone explain me the reason ?

Comment: You asked basically the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827680/what-privileges-does-vfork-child-possess. Don't do anything else than vfork()/exec().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`vfork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/vfork.html) function was part of POSIX 2004, but is not part of POSIX 2008, which is the current edition (aka [POSIX 2016](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)).  What you can do with `vfork()` is very, very limited.  The manual says:

> The `vfork()` function shall be equivalent to `fork()`, except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type `pid_t` used to store the return value from `vfork()`, or returns from the function in which `vfork()` was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling `_exit()` or one of the `exec` family of functions.

You can't call `close()` from the child; you can't call `write()`.

### TL;DR — Don't use `vfork()`.

If you're brave and happy with the complexity of the interface, you could investigate the [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) function and its support crew of 20+ functions starting `posix_spawn_`.  OTOH, the "`fork()` and then do the operations in the child" paradigm from classic Unix has a lot of merits; it is a lot easier to understand than the `posix_spawn` functions, and ultimately more flexible too.  Not all platforms necessarily implement `posix_spawn()`, either.